# Cannot view allauth login and signup pages

Tags: python, django

I have been following a tutorial on YouTube to create a facebook login and signup process using allauth
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmHn5XYlgto

However, I whenever I try and visit the url /accounts/login the page loaded is my index/home page. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Here is my urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from catalog import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('courses/', views.courses, name='courses'),
    path('course-details/', views.coursedetails, name='course-details'),
    path('accounts/',include('allauth.urls')),
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sendemail.apps.SendemailConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'django_extensions'
]
SITE_ID = 1
...
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

This is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
#home page view
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
#about page
def about(request):
    return render(request, "about-us.html")
#courses page
def courses(request):
    return render(request, "courses.html")
#the course details page
def coursedetails(request):
    return render(request,"course-details.html")
```

Comment: post your login view also

Comment: @bmons I have posted it

Comment: what i mean is your view.py file for login

Comment: @bmons oh sorry, have updated

Comment: if you dont have specific view for login, you can call login in your templates {% url 'account_login' %} if your are using django allauth

Comment: @bmons tried calling {% url 'account_login' %} in my login,html file. When I run manage.py I can't seem to go to accounts/login account/login or account-login url

Comment: create a login view authenticate user and make the url for the view, then you can access it